# Angular: how to use ngx-translate in root component?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I want to set global setting for ng-select, the "notFoundText" as translated value by ngx-translate TranslateService:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    public translate: TranslateService,
    private readonly ngSelectConfig: NgSelectConfig
  ) {
    translate.addLangs(['pl-PL']);
    translate.setDefaultLang('pl-PL');

    this.ngSelectConfig.notFoundText =
      this.translate.instant('GENERAL.NO_DATA');
  }
}
```

In this implementation, `translate.instant()` returns "GENERAL.NO_DATA" instead of translated text. It works in several places (also in several modules, so generally my configuration works), but it does not work in root component. 'GENERAL.NO_DATA' also exists in my JSON file, because i'm using it for a long time.

How can I use TranslateService in this component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got this problem when i work with ngx-translate first time. When `app-component` is inited, translate service hasn't finished the  configuration yet so when you get translate text by `instant` method, it doesn't work and the result will be `GENERAL.NO_DATA`.

Solution: You should use `get` method

```
this.translate.get('GENERAL.NO_DATA').pipe(
take(1)
).subscribe(text => this.ngSelectConfig.notFoundText = text);
```